# Azure Web Site Kudu Publishing failing with timeout

Tags: azure, kudu

I have a custom deployment script (*.sh script) defined for my azure deployment.

Just today, I have found that I am unable to publish. I updated my bitbucket repository and after a while I get an error similar to the following:

`Command 'starter.cmd deploy_pvl_cont ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 180 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.\r\nstarter.cmd deploy_pvl_content.sh`

I have tried a number of things to try to diagnose the problem.

- Increase SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT to 300
- Run the script locally (Works)
- Set up a new fresh deployment slot and try publishing same commit (Same error)
- Tried publishing the previously successful commit (Same error)
- Look for useful error messages in a diagnostic log dump (Coldn't find anything more useful)
- Tried running the deployment script from the Kudu Console (No output returned, like it didn't actually run)
- Tried reverting git to a previous version as suggested by @david-ebbo
- Tried simplifying my script to a single echo command with the same results

Not sure what I can do to debug this further. Ideally I would like to get the output of the shell script on the azure host but don't know how to get it. Any ideas?

Comment: How long does it take to execute this script on local machine

Comment: On my local machine it takes around a minute. Previous publishes on Azure have taken 180 seconds. Note: I just edited my question to show that I did try increasing the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT and while it did wait longer it failed with the same message.

Comment: If you're able to find the specific command that triggers this and repro it directly from Kudu Console outside of your script, that would be a good step to isolate the issue (e.g. see [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues)). Is your script batch or bash?

Comment: While it's stuck, you can also look at Kudu Process explorer which might indicate which process it's stuck in. Also, can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This may help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Hi David, the site is https://stage.pvlighthouse.com.au. I will look into the other suggestions soon.

Comment: @Sudsy I posted an answer. It may very well not be what you're running into, but give that you have a bash script, I feel it's likely related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated answer

This is a regression caused by the move to git 2.8.x in Azure. The issue is tracked by https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2041.

Here is a very simple workaround (and you *don't* need to bring in the old git tools): instead of setting your `COMMAND` to `deploy_pvl_content.sh`, set it to `bash deploy_pvl_content.sh`

We'll address the issue, but this workaround will get you going.

### Original answer (only leaving for context)

You could be running into some flavor of [this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bdf94308-1bae-4812-be84-9667b24cfc0f/deploy-fail-on-permission-denied-user-is-not-what-i-expect?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview), which is caused by the upgrade to git 2.8.1 that we just did.

While we're trying to get to the bottom of it, please try this workaround to see if that helps:

- Go to Kudu Console
- Create a `d:\home\bin` folder
- Copy the old Windows git 1.8.x folder in there. You can get the content from [here](https://davidebbostorage.blob.core.windows.net/public/gitbin1.8.4.zip). If you drag and drop the zip into Kudu console, there is a special unzip drop area that will expand it.
- Try your deployment again

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Looking at the process explorer, the process that hangs around without exiting is git-bash.exe with a sub process of mintty.exe .

The zip that you asked me to install had git.exe but not git-bash.exe, not sure if that's related.

Comment: Managed to work out a few things. git pull works just fine on the kudu console and it was showing that the repo was up to date.

I was also able to run the deployment command with ```bash .\deploy_pvl_content.sh``` and it ran all of the steps correctly until right at the end when running kudusync. It get's this error:

```Error: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\artifacts\manifest'.```

I can confirm that the artifacts path does not appear in kudu console.

Comment: Just tried creating the artifacts folder but it didn't resolve the issue unfortunately. Seemed to fix part of the problem, but it hit another exception which was difficult to understand.

Comment: The deployment script behaves differently when run by itself because the env is not fully set up, which is why it tries to create a manifest folder (see script for details). What you want to do is find the individual command from the script that's causing issue, and not run the whole script.

Comment: If I switched to a bat file for deployment would it be able to give a better error log in the azure console than the shell script allows? In other words, rather than just displaying a timeout on failure is it more likely to give a full log.

Comment: Not sure that would make a difference. In either case I'd expect any echo line from the script to make it to the log. But if it's stuck in a specific command, then there is probably not output at all during that time. Note that git is not needed in the zip I shared and you can delete it.

Comment: OK, so I simplified my deployment script to:

```echo "Hello"```

And I get the same timeout.

I tried with the files you sent me in the /home/bin directory and I get the same result.

Comment: I'm now able to repro. Issue opened: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2041