# Failed to deploy from bitbucket on Azure App Service

Tags: git, azure, deployment, bitbucket, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I tried to deploy program from bitbucket to Azure App Service but got encountered the following error.
I searched but cannot find the solution.

> One or more errors occurred.
>   Command 'git checkout master ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 60 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.\ngit checkout master --force

I appreciate any advice.
Thank you

Comment: This happened because it was going so slow that KUDU failed to detect activity for 60 seconds and aborted the build. Here is the similar [issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1693).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David said, it may caused by the upgrade to git 2.8.1, so you could try [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739407/azure-web-site-kudu-publishing-failing-with-timeout):

1·Go to KUDU Console.

·Create a d:\home\bin folder

·Copy the old Windows git 1.8.x folder in there. If you drag and drop the zip into Kudu console, there is a special unzip drop area that will expand it.

·Try your deployment again.

2.Or you don't need to bring in the old git tools and reset your command. The [issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2041) is tracked as 2041.

3.You can set `SCM_BUILD_ARGS=/p:UseSharedCompilation=false`. This disables running the compiler as a server. Refer from this [issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1693).

4.Set the `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT` and `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` to a long time.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT" value="100000" />
    <add key="WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT" value="100000" />
</appSettings>
```

If increasing the timeout doesn't help, you might be in a situation where [deployment is stuck](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/30436586-how-to-get-more-insight-into-what-is-going-on). e.g. that could happen if something is prompting for user input that can never come.

One thing to try:

·set a really long timeout

·do a deployment do it gets stuck

·use Kudu process explorer to see if you can spot anything suspicious in the process tree. Also, look at the deployment logs which may give hints about where it's stuck.